# Copied my asp.net project folder to open it in my laptop, and css stopped working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on an asp.net project and i'm doing some css stuff. On my Desktop, it works as it was supposed to. But when i try to open it on my laptop, my css doesn't work anymore.

One example is the usage of the 'placeholder' atribute in an asp.textbox. At home, it works on every browser i have (IE, Firefox and Chrome). On my laptop, this property doesn't work. My widths are broken as well.

Did i do something wrong? I thought that only copying the project folder would be enough...or there's something else i should've done?

Comment: Different OS/Browser combition on the other machine I'd imagine. However there is no way anyone can debug this without using psychic powers, or playing 21 questions.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think one common mistake is having mismatching paths when you copy from one machine to another (at least in my workarea it is!) did you double check the paths to your CSS in code and filesystem? if the ASP.Net engine cant find the files it wont be able to use them.